# How do I properly use moment.js to change the format of my timestamp?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have date in a long format in my **data.json** file

```
"start_time"    : "1435377480000"
```

I want to use [**moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) to turn those long format to an actual date format.

## I've tried

```
start_time.html(moment(objects[x].start_time).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mmA"));
```

---

## Result

View

[image]

Any helps / hints will help a lot at this point.

Comment: what is returned in objects and x?

Comment: **objects** =  is all the object in my json file.

Comment: **x** =  is just an argument of my `updateInfo()` function.

Comment: Please ignore `objects[x]` - they're error free.

Comment: Close ?? What did I do wrong that you want to close my post ? Please explain so I can improve or learn.

Comment: When I run `moment(1435377480000)` I get: `Fri Jun 26 2015 22:58:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)` as the date.

Comment: Okay, you're very close. What if I want to print in this format `MM/DD/YYYY h:mmA` ?

Comment: `moment(1435377480000).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A")` => "06/26/2015 10:58 PM"

Comment: @tymeJV : I followed you, I got **invalid date**

Comment: `start_time.html(moment(objects[x].start_time).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"));`

Comment: Try this: `start_time.html(parseInt(moment(objects[x].start_time)).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just keep making syntax errors. Happens to the best of us! Anyway, this should work:

```
start_time.html(moment(objects[x].start_time).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mmA"));
```

You were passing in an object to moment but not saying to do anything with it, and then passing in the date format as a second value to HTML instead of to moment itself.

One more thing is that your start_time is a string, so turn it into an integer with `parseInt` and you should be good.

Edit: Apparently moment does accept strings, but OP said using parseInt solved his problem.

Comment: **Uncaught ReferenceError: parsInt is not defined**

Comment: Your suggestion, I still get **invalid date**. I'm sorry. I'm not sure why.

Comment: @tymeJV: I just follow your answer.

Comment: Ah so I did spell it wrong. You're still getting invalid date? Your code is working on my machine. Have you passed the date string into JavaScript's vanilla Date() function constructor and see if the date you're working with is right? Maybe the date string is just malformed or something.

Comment: It works with `parseInt()` - if I take it out, I doesn't work. Is it the right behavior ?

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, and your helps through out the comments.

Comment: No problem! We're all here to help eachother out. It's hard to know since I can't see the JSON, but in this case if it works then it's the right behavior. The strange thing is that moment SHOULD accept strings, apparently. Odd. Maybe the string is malformed? I don't know.